# What will be the IUPAC name of this organic compound and why?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

[image: 5-hydroxycyclopent-2-en-1-one]

I cannot understand how to name this compound. The answer is 5-Hydroxycyclopent-2-enone but shouldn't the $\ce{-OH}$ group be given more priority than alkene?

Answer (score 3):

The most important simplified criteria for the numbering of simple cyclic compounds are:

1. lower locants for suffixes
2. lower locants for multiple bonds
3. lower locants for prefixes
4. lower locants for substituents cited first as a prefix in the name

The corresponding actual wording in the current version of *[Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry – IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013 (Blue Book)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069)* reads as follows:

> **P-14.4** NUMBERING
>
> When several structural features appear in cyclic and acyclic compounds, low locants are assigned to them in the following decreasing order of seniority:
>
> (…)
>
> (c) principal characteristic groups and free valences (suffixes);
>
> (…)
>
> (e) saturation/unsaturation:
>
> (i) low locants are given to hydro/dehydro prefixes (…) and ‘ene’ and ‘yne’ endings;
>
> (ii) low locants are given first to multiple bonds as a set and then to double bonds (…);
>
> (f) detachable alphabetized prefixes, all considered together in a series of increasing numerical order;
>
> (g) lowest locants for the substituent cited first as a prefix in the name;
>
> (…)

Therefore, when assigning locants to the compound that is given in the question, the lowest locant is given first to the suffix for the principal characteristic group according to (c), i.e. ‘…-1-one’. Then, a low locant is given to the double bond according to (e), i.e. ‘…-2-en-…’. Finally, a low locant is given to the prefix for the hydroxy substituent according to (f), i.e. ‘5-hydroxy…’. Thus, the complete name is **5-hydroxycyclopent-2-en-1-one.**

[image: 5-hydroxycyclopent-2-en-1-one]

Answer (score 1):

That astonished me now, too. I checked on the IUPAC rules and it says that only the group with the highest priority is to mention all the others are just added alphabetically. So I guess you will take the highest priority + its corresponding carbon chain. This is like the molecule you start with and you can add additional functional groups which don't influence the priority anymore. (But as I said only a guess on this one or how I interpret that line in their rules).